# For some reason when i click the button in mainactivity it isnt calling the next activity specified

Tags: android, kotlin

MAINACTIVITY :

```
package com.example.pushpulllegs

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_preloginactivity.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button :Button =findViewById(R.id.button3)
        val intent2 = Intent(this, MythirdActivity::class.java)
    button.setOnClickListener(){

    startActivity(intent2);
    }


    }


}
class MythirdActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dataentry)
    }
}
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.093" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.232"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

dataentry.kt

```
    package com.example.pushpulllegs

    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.LinearLayout
    import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


    class dataentry : AppCompatActivity() {




        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           var cardViewCount =0  ;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dataentry)
            val sbmitbtn : Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)
            val inputtxt : EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)

            val cardview :CardView = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.myCardView);

    sbmitbtn.setOnClickListener(){
        var inputtext = inputtxt.text.toString();
        val intent = Intent(this, MySecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("myText", "This is my input data")
        cardview.id = View.generateViewId() + cardViewCount;

        cardViewCount++ ;

        startActivity(intent)
        val myLinearLayout :LinearLayout= findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.myLinearLayout1)
        myLinearLayout.addView(cardview);

    }



    
        }

    }
    class MySecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    }
```

activity_dataentry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dataentry">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.363" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to add a cardview in the mainactivity.kt from dataentry.kt .I apologize beforehand if i am asking a stupid question or if my way of asking is incorrect. When i click the button in mainactivity its supposed to call dataentry.layout ,but for some reason nothing happens.I have checked the android manifest and the activities have been declared there. I am new to Kotlin so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `onClickListener` firing? Put a log inside the method to see if the button fires when you press it.

Comment: Your intent you're calling in the button is starting `MythirdActivity`, not `dataentry`. That's a terrible class name for code readability, by the way. You should name it `DataEntryActivity`.

Comment: Figured it out.Thank you for your constructive criticism.